# Prove that limit of function does not exist, if and only if sequence $f(s_n)$ is not convergent.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, proof-writing, sequence-of-function

I don't understand the hint (in bold) to prove this problem.

**Problem**:
Let $f: D \rightarrow  \mathbb{R}$ and let $c$ be an accumulation point of D. Then the following are equivalent:

(a) $f$ does not have a limit at $c$.
(b) There exists a sequence $(s_n)$ in $D$ with each $s_n \ne c$ such that $(s_n)$ converges to $c$, but $f((s_n))$ is not convergent in $\mathbb{R}$.

**Hint**:
To prove that $(a) \Rightarrow (b)$, suppose that (b) is false. Let $s_n$ be a sequence with $s_n \rightarrow c$. Before we can use Theorem 20.8, we must show that given ***any*** sequence $(t_n)$ in $D$ with $t_n \Rightarrow c$, we have limit $f(t_n)=L$.

We only know from the negation of (b) that $(f(t_n))$ is convergent. **To see that $\lim f(t_n) = L$, consider the sequence $(u_n) = (s_1, t_1, s_2, t_2...)$ and note that $(f(s_n))$ and $(f(t_n))$ are both subsequences of $(f(u_n))$.**

**My question:**
The hint wants for *any* sequence $(t_n)$. But, how does $(u_n)$ help showing $(t_n)$ is any sequence? What do I need $(u_n)$ for?

The proof is [here](https://www.math.uh.edu/%7Ealmus/4389_AN_part2.pdf#page=13) under Theorem 2.

Comment: As far as I understand, you first suppose $t_n$ is any sequence, then construct $u_n$ based on $t_n$, and not the other way around.

Comment: I am not sure to understand why you need to construct the sequence $(u_n)$ from $(t_n)$. To prove $(a)$ implies $(b)$, you can assume that $(a)$ holds and $(b)$ is false and show that these two assumptions together produce a contradiction, ie an inconsistency. Here $b$ false means: for any sequence $(s_n)$ that converges to $c$, the sequence $(f(s_n))$ converges, which more or less (a long time not did this kind of thing) the definition of $f$ having a limit at $c$.

Comment: @MarcDinh It's also proved here (Theorem 2 at the bottom), https://www.math.uh.edu/%7Ealmus/4389_AN_part2.pdf#page=13 They also used $(u_n)$ and $(t_n)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some fixed sequence $(s_n)$ such that $s_n\to c$. Then take any other sequence $(t_n)$ such that $t_n\to c$. By negating $(b)$ we know that $(f(s_n))$ and $(f(t_n))$ are both convergent, but the critical part is to notice that you don't know a priori that the limits are the same. If you knew that the limits are the same, you would prove that $f$ has a limit at $c$.

To prove that $(f(s_n))$ and $(f(t_n))$ converge to the same limit, you consider $(u_n)$ defined as in the text. Obviously, $u_n\to c$. What you now know is that $(f(u_n))$, $(f(s_n))$ and $(f(t_n))$ are all convergent and that $(f(s_n))$ and $(f(t_n))$ are subsequences of $(f(u_n))$. Finally, any subsequence of a convergent sequence is convergent with the same limit. So,

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}f(t_n)=\lim_{n\to\infty}f(u_n)=\lim_{n\to\infty}f(s_n).$$

Since $(t_n)$ was arbitrary, it means that for all sequences $t_n\to c$, $f(t_n)\to L$, where $L = \lim_nf(s_n)$. Therefore, $f$ has a limit at $c$.

Comment: Silly question, is this the negation of (b): **For all** sequences $(s_n)$ in $D$ with each $s_n \ne c$ such that $(s_n)$ converges to $c$, **and** $(f(s_n))$ **is** convergent in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @user13985, $(\forall s\colon \mathbb N \to D\setminus\{c\})\ s_n\to c \implies \exists \lim_nf(s_n).$ Remember that $\neg(P\to Q) \equiv P\wedge \neg Q$.

Comment: I deleted my comment, but is what I wrote up there now correct? If not, would you mind write the correct one in statements?

Comment: @user13985, no, simply because $\neg (P\wedge \neg Q) \not\equiv P \wedge Q$. What I wrote reads: "For all sequences $(s_n)$ in $D\setminus\{c\}$, if $(s_n)$ converges to $c$, then $(f(s_n))$ converges."

Comment: The negation states "For all sequences...".  sn't it already implying all possible sequences? Why do we still need $(s_n)$ and $(t_n)$ to prove the limit?

Comment: @user13985, I wrote the reasoning in my answer. Even though you know all the limits exist, you don't know that they are the same, so you need to prove that all of the limits are equal.

Comment: Yes, to the SAME limit! That part should be extra bold. :)

Comment: If I understand your proof correctly: By (b), if every sequence $s_n$ in $D$ \ {c} is convergent, then $f(s_n)$ is convergent in $\mathbb{R}$. Let $s_n$ and $t_n$ be any arbitrary subsequences. They each must be convergent. Combine $(s_n)$ and $(t_n)$ and call it the new sequence $(u_n)$. Since $u_n$ is convergent, then its subsequences must have the same limit. So, $\lim u_n = \lim s_n = \lim t_n$. We can repeat this for any sequence in $D$. Hence, it it proved.

Comment: @user13985, no, that's incorrect. Negation of (b) says: "for every sequence $(s_n)$ in $D\setminus\{c\}$, **if $(s_n)$ converges to $c$**, then $f(s_n)$ converges in $\mathbb R$." Don't take arbitrary sequences, take arbitrary sequences that **coverge to $c$**. Combine those sequences into $(u_n)$ and conclude that $(u_n)$ **converges to $c$**. Now, you should look at $(f(s_n)),\ (f(t_n))$ and $(f(u_n))$, apply the negation of (b) and conclude that they converge in $\mathbb R$. Finally, $(f(s_n))$ and $(f(t_n))$ are subsequences of $(f(u_n))$, so they have the same limit.

Comment: I see my problem. There are some sequences $(s_n)$, which does not converge to $c$. Preciseness is important.

Comment: The original theorem says: "for every sequence $s_n \Rightarrow c$ with $s_n \in D$ and $s_n \ne c$ for all $n$, the sequence $(f(s_n))$ converges to $L$." They didn't use if.., then... Not sure if it makes any difference,

Comment: @user13985, how would you write it formally?

Comment: Is this a rhetorical question? I'd write it as: "for every sequence $(s_n)$ in $D$ that converges to $c$ with $s_n \ne c$ for all $n$, the sequence $(f(s_n))$ converges to $L$."

Comment: @user13985, it's not rhetorical. I meant how would you write it using quantifiers and logical connectives?